# Provide a Repository class for my asp.net mvc web application. How to make sure i am disposing eveything correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dispose

I have a question about how i need to manage my Dispose method, when i am implementing a repository class inside my asp.net mvc web application.

Currently i have the following:-

1. i am using VS 2013, and i created a new asp.net mvc-5 web application.
2. i uses entity framework 6.0 to map my database  tables inside my web application and generates a .edmx file.
3. I created a new Controller class for one of my model objects, using "MVC 5 controller , using entity framework" scaffold .

now inside the generated controller class i got this dispose method:-

```
 public class DeptsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
//code goes here
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

now i want to move my data access code to be inside a separate Repository class, and to be initiating my DbContext object inside the Repository class rather than inside the controller class.

so i created the following repository class:-

```
public class repository

    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        //code goes here...
        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
```

and i modified my controller class to be using the repository class as follow:-

```
 public class DeptsController : Controller
    {
        //private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private repository repo = new repository();
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                repo.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

so can anyone adivce on the following :-

1. since i will be moving my data access logic to be inside my repository , so what else i need to dispose other than the DbContext ? i mean before using the Repository , calling  `base.Dispose(disposing);` inside the controller will make sure all the unmanaged resources are disposed correctly.. but when i moved my data access to be inside the repository , how i can make sure that all the unmanaged resources consumed by the repository are disposed ?? and is calling base.Disposed(disposing) inside the controller class , will also dispose any unmanaged resources consumed inside the repository class ?

Can anyone adivce on this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you don't need to do anything else to dispose of `DbContext` in `Repository` class.

If you have **more resources** in `Repository` class then you will need to add their `.Dispose()` call in `Repository.Dispose` and that will be it.

`base.Dispose(disposing)` in `DeptsController` class calls `Dispose` method of it's **base class**, i.e. `Controller`... that's so base class can dispose of resources it's internally using - nothing you should worry about.

Comment: now let say i have to open files , upload images, read from external .csv files inside my repository class, how i can make sure all these unmanaged resources got disposed correctly ??... now as i know that any Controller class at the end will call Garabage Collector,, so calling base.Dispose() inside my controller class will make sure all these unmanaged resources are disposed,, but in my case i am creating a new repository class, which does not have any base class to handle the garbage collector ,......

Comment: for example on this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application they call the following "GC.SuppressFinalize(this);" iniside the repository class and also the reposiory class implements IDisposable ,, so not sure if i need to follow this approach also ?

Comment: @johnG If you are that deep in thinking you definitely need to start testing concrete example and track memory usage in Visual Studio. But all of the stuff you are mentioning are easy to handle - if you start uploading images / reading external csv files, etc - you'll probably be doing that in `using()` blocks which dispose right away, so they shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @johnG And be aware that link you're looking is like 3 years old. Entity Framework has change A LOT since that - it's COMPLETELY different now. So, I definitely advise you to start coding and **testing** the things you want to do - at this point you are probably dwelling into analysis-paralysis territory ;)

Comment: what have changed in entity framework now regarding Disposing resources ? i am not following the link ,, as i am creating mvc-5 with entity framework 6.. but i provide the link as an example

Comment: i know that reading files, upload images ,etc can be disposed by providing using blocks,,, but at the end making sure that everything is disposed correctly is a good practice,, just incase one developer forget to dispose his/her code ... so i need to provide a way to make sure everything is disposed ,, even if our code will be disposing its self on block bases...

Comment: @johnG `using` WILL make sure that the resource is disposed of. in fact it's _better_ than `Dispose` because you can't guarantee that a user of your class will call `Dispose`.

Comment: @DStanley i can make sure a user of my class call Dispose in case i implement the IDisposable for my repo class ? is this correct ?again i do not want to 100% rely on the  Dispose method to handle disposing the resources , i need it as a plan B in case one developer forget to dispose his code correctly.. hope this clear what i am asking ..

Comment: No -- you can't force clients to call `Dispose`.  They _should_, but there's nothing that can force them to.  That's why `using` is better - then YOU are in control of when resources are released. And you don't need a plan B.  Either release them in the method that creates them (preferably with `using`) or dispose of them in `Dispose`; not both.  The latter is only necessary when you want the _client_ to control when that happens.  If _you_ can control it you should.

Comment: @DStanley but if i can not force the class users to call Dispose ,, then i can not force them to use using block also,,!!

Comment: @DStanley so how i can make sure my repository is able to dispose its self using the Dispose method ?? currently i have the following inside the repo.Dispose() {db.Dispose()} do i need to call the GC.SuppressFinalize(this); also ?

Comment: You can't. If the client calls `Dispose` then you will be fine,  If not, then once there are no references to the repository the GC will clean it up, you just don't know when. You only need to call GC.SuppressFinalize _when you have a finalizer_.  You only need a finalizer when you create unmanaged resources.  In the cases you mention you are not.

Comment: @DStanley I'm starting to think that we are being trolled... check out his question history - there are like 4 similar questions ;)

Comment: @D Stanley so at the end ,, i did not get what i need to provide inside my repository to make sure all my managed and unmanaged resources will be disposed correctly ... ?? now in my case my repo will be consuming managed and unmanaged code... can u adivce ?

Answer (score 1):

Contexts are not meant to be kept open indefinitely. They are meant to be created when needed, used, and disposed after you're done.

In addition, ASP.NET is a stateless platform, so your context will be garbage collected when the response is done anyways.

So your repository does not need to implement `IDispoasable`, and thus your controller does not either.  Create a `DbContext` within a `using` block in your repository, and it will be disposed automatically.

However...

> how i can make sure that all the unmanaged resources consumed by the repository are disposed ?

That's what `Dispose` is for.  Whatever creates disposable objects is responsible for disposing of them. So if you create disposable objects in your repository and can't immediately dispose of them (for whatever reason), then you need to dispose of them in the `Dispose` method. If you don't inherit from a disposable base class, then there's no base dispose to call; otherwise you should call the base dispose to make sure the base class disposes of any resources

> is calling `base.Disposed(disposing)` inside the controller class , will also dispose any unmanaged resources consumed inside the repository class ?

No.  Calling `base.Dispose` calls the base class's `Dispose` method.  The base class has no knowledge of the repository, so calling `base.Dispose` does nothing in regard to disposing of the respository.  That is done in your controller's `Dispose` method when you call `repo.Dispose()`.

> calling base.Dispose(disposing); inside the controller will make sure all the unmanaged resources are disposed correctly.

Well, it makes sure all unmanaged (and managed `IDisposable`) resources *created by the base class* are disposed of.  And resources created by your derived controller should be disposed of in the overridden `Dispose` method (which you are doing).

Comment: @D Stanley my question is not about disposing DBConect specifically, now my repository class might handle & consume unmanaged resources such as reading .csv file, uploading images, etc. so how i can make sure these unmanged resources are disposed correctly.I mean before having the repository class, calling base.Dispose() inside the controller class will make sure these unmanaged resources will be disposed since the base controller class will call the garbage collector. but in my case i introduce a new repository class, which does not have any base class which handle the GC?? is this correct?

Comment: Whatever creates disposable objects is responsible for disposing of them.  So if you create disposable objects in your repository and can't immediately dispose of them (for whatever reason), then you need to dispose of them in the `Dispose` method.  If you don't inherit from a disposable base class, then there's no base dispose to call,; otherwise you should call the base dispose to make sure the base class disposes of any resources.

Comment: also `Dispose` does not "call the garbage collector".  That is done by the system when there is memory pressure.  The whole point of `Dispose` is to release unmanaged resources (file handles, database connections, etc) in a timely manner.  The resources will get release eventually whwnever the garbage collector runs.

Comment: @D Stanley so are you saying that explicitly disposing my code is not necessary ? can you adivce more on this please?

Comment: @D Stanley now just to keep my question specific,, now i want to be disposing the resources the soonest , so even if these resources will be released on timely basis by calling the GC, my question is what i need to provide inside my repository class, to make sure any unmanaged resources (beside the DBConext which i explicitly disposing it) will be disposed the soonest ?

Comment: You should dispose of them _as soon as you don't need them anymore_.  If for some reason you use class properties to hold on to these resources, that means disposing of them in `Dispose`. The best method, however, is to use `using` blocks to dispose of them _within the method that creates them_.  That's why I suggest not using a class member for the context.  dispose of the context when you're done with it and you don;t have to worry about disposing of it,

Comment: @D Stanley that what we always follow we use using blocks to make sure every thing is disposed the soonest,, but what if one of the developer forget to dispose his related code,, so i want to make sure i have a plan B which will dispose everything that were not disposed.. so in this case i need to make sure my repo class is able to dispose itself ? is this correct ? if the answer is Yes then i return back to my original question,,, how i can handle this inside the repo class? is calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this); inside my repository a valid approach to follow? i am a bit confused now

Comment: No - YOU dispose of items when you are done with them, the worst that happens if a developer doesn't dispose of a resource he/she creates is that it will get released when the garbage collector runs.  The point of Dispose is doing that _sooner_ - it will get cleaned up eventually either way. You can't force a class to "dispose of itself".

Comment: @D Stanley so what will be disposed by the garbage collector ? everything ? even the DbContext itself, if it was not disposed correctly ? as i know the GC will dispose any managed resources such as used memory by the system variables , but the GC can not dispose unmanaged resources such as opening external .csv file (assuming it was opened without a using block)?? second point ,, how i can manage the frequency of the GC trigger ?

Comment: The GC will clean up any managed resources that do not have active references.  _Unmanaged_ resources should be cleaned up in the Dispose method, with the finalizer as a last resort. You are not dealing with unmanaged resources, though - you are dealing with `File` and `DbContext` that are managed, so they will clean up the unmanaged resources that they create (file handles, database connections) when they are disposed of (or cleared by the GC).

Comment: @D Stanley so what is considered as unmanged resources can you provide an example? and how i can dispose them in the dispose method? can you adivce more on this please ?